# How to Filter the query result for pagination in TableClient.QueryAsync() [Azure.Data.Tables]

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I am using the **Azure.Data.Tables** package & **TableClient.QueryAsync()** method to get the query result.
I wants the result to use it for **pagination**. I came across this code in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableclient.queryasync?view=azure-dotnet

```
Pageable<T> pageable = client.QueryAsync<T>(filter : value, maxPerPage : 10);
```

What are the changes should I make ?

Thanks in Advance !! :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a snippet from our [samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/tables/Azure.Data.Tables/tests/samples).

```
AsyncPageable<TableEntity> queryResultsMaxPerPage = tableClient.QueryAsync<TableEntity>(filter: $"PartitionKey eq '{partitionKey}'", maxPerPage: 10);
    
                await foreach (Page<TableEntity> page in queryResultsMaxPerPage.AsPages())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("This is a new page!");
                    foreach (TableEntity qEntity in page.Values)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"# of {qEntity.GetString("Product")} inventoried: {qEntity.GetInt32("Quantity")}");
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Hi, I have gone through the code snippet before, but couldn't get any idea to use it for pagination.

Comment: Suppose in case of pagination, I'm on page 2, I want entities from count 10 to 20. How can I do that. Coluld you please lead to that. Thanks !!

Comment: Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/pagination

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by creating an extension method for `IAsyncEnumerable` which will return the first item of an `IAsyncEnumerable`. After calling `AsPages()` on the `AsyncPageable<T> query` you have an `IAsyncEnumerable<Page<T>>` from which you can get the first page with this method.

```
static class IAsyncEnumerableExtensions
    {
        public static async Task<T?> FirstOrDefault<T>(this IAsyncEnumerable<T> asyncEnumerable)
        {
            await foreach (var item in asyncEnumerable)
            {
                return item;
            }
            return default;
        }
    }
```

The `Page<T>` object has a `continuationToken` property which can be passed to the `AsPages(string)` method, so you can get the next page with:

```
query.AsPages(continuationToken).FirstOrDefault();
```

In order to be able to get the previous page you will have to cache the continuationTokens, or for the first page just call `query.AsPages().FirstOrDefault();` (without a continuationToken).

Check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableclient.queryasync?view=azure-dotnet) for more details (click through the parameter and return types).

I used [this example](https://medium.com/medialesson/azure-table-storage-pagination-in-angular-2-d29212d2b320) as inspiration for the token caching. You can also look for examples using the Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table library, here a similar concept is used with ContinuationTokens.

Comment: To add to this, if you want to use LINQ (including FirstOrDefault) on IAsyncEnumerable, you could also use the [System.Linq.Async package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async/)

Comment: I Agree with Erra, this implementation is rather dangerous in that it is not honoring cancellation tokens. My answer below reflects what I learned from this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/november/csharp-iterating-with-async-enumerables-in-csharp-8

Answer (score 4):

The key to achieve pagination is passing so-called **ContinuationToken** back and forth. When the extension method is defined as following:

```
public static class TableReader
{
    public static async Task<Page<T>> GetPageAsync<T>(this TableClient client, string filter, int pageSize, string continuationToken) 
        where T: class, ITableEntity, new()
    {
        AsyncPageable<T> pageable = client.QueryAsync<T>(filter, pageSize);

        await using (IAsyncEnumerator<Page<T>> enumerator = pageable.AsPages(continuationToken).GetAsyncEnumerator())
        {
            await enumerator.MoveNextAsync();
            return enumerator.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

the return type of **Page** comprises both the data of single page and a token that can be used to obtain next page. The demonstration of the usage of this method could be:

```
string connectionString = "TODO: your connection string";
string tableName = "TODO: your table";
string filter = "TODO: your filter";
int pageSize = 1;  //TODO: your page size

TableClient client = new TableClient(connectionString, tableName);

// continuationToken is used iterate through pages
string continuationToken = null;
while (true)
{
    // take next page
    Page<TableEntity> page = await client.GetPageAsync<TableEntity>(filter, pageSize, continuationToken);
    foreach (TableEntity tableEntity in page.Values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(tableEntity.RowKey);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("=== end of current page ===");

    // if there are no more pages, we're done
    if (page.ContinuationToken == null)
    {
        break;
    }

    // there are more pages => we can continue reading if we want
    Console.WriteLine("> Press Y to load next page");
    if (Console.ReadKey().Key.ToString().ToLower() != "y") { break; }

    // cache the token to be used later to obtain next page
    continuationToken = page.ContinuationToken;
}

Console.WriteLine("=== end of data ===");
```

Of course, you would use your own type implementing **ITableEntity** with additional properties instead of the basic TableEntity to parametrize the **GetPageAsync** method.

Answer (score 3):

I can empathize with your question; I was banging my head against the wall on this for a while.

EDIT: This may fit your use case also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/pagination#take-the-first-n-elements if your filter determines the lex ordering and a simple take count is used.

> Here is a snippet from our [samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/tables/Azure.Data.Tables/tests/samples).

Nope, this is NOT helpful, if anything it is determinantal in its current form. I cannot help but nit on this; I've spent days going over those "samples", reviewing the underlying source code, the tests themselves, and god knows how many times I have re-read [MIGRATION GUIDE](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.Data.Tables_12.6.1/sdk/tables/Azure.Data.Tables/MigrationGuide.md). While these samples would be somewhat high-level example of usage in a Console App perhaps as a Service Worker, however it doesn't give ANY guidance in where the **lion share** of APIs would be using this, i.e. repository pattern in a microservice. [Don't even get me started on the TestEnvironment base class](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/da47271b8faabc1b61d419b9d0741061154c0482/sdk/core/Azure.Core.TestFramework/src/TestEnvironment.cs#L26)

Even reviewing the SDK guideline for Azure.* packages offer little of the HOW, just a generous helping of '...' [Paging](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/dotnet_introduction.html#dotnet-paging). That leaves devs back to square one and in my own experience I ended up with now more questions than answers.

Another unreal oversight is cancellation tokens, so I will address that elephant while I am here.

Now let's focus on answering the question with a functional example of what could be used in an application. I currently use this in my own production application:

```
// Background context: Class is a data provider class that gets videos from a video table of an ephemeral nature.
// Periodically the InitializeAsync is called to create the table client and instantiate a new table since the entire table is deleted after running the associated batch processing.
// This is specific to my use case and you can easily revert to
// having the TableClient specified via ctor injection instead with a DI Singleton registration.
public class VideoTable : IVideoTable
{
    private readonly TableServiceClient service;
    private readonly IOptionsMonitor<BotConfiguration> settings;
    private readonly ILogger<VideoTable> logger;

    private TableClient client;

    // For mocking instantances
    protected VideoTable() { }

    public VideoTable(TableServiceClient service, IOptionsMonitor<BotConfiguration> settings, ILogger<VideoTable> logger)
    {
        logger.LogDebug("{Object} constructed", GetType().Name);

        this.service = service;
        this.settings = settings;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task InitalizeAsync(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        _ = await service.CreateTableIfNotExistsAsync(settings.CurrentValue.Storage.Table.Videos.Name, ct).Go(); // Note: to explain where this comes from: I got tired of writing '.ConfigureAwait(false);' so I made this extension method, simply remove them and you'll obtain the same functionality

        client = service.GetTableClient(settings.CurrentValue.Storage.Table.Videos.Name);
    }

    public async IAsyncEnumerable<Page<VideoEntity>> GetVideosPaginatedAsync(int pageNumber, int perPageCount, [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var accumulator = 0;
        var total  = pageNumber * perPageCount; // say we want page 3 with 10 items per page we'll go to 30 here
        var select = client.QueryAsync<VideoEntity>(maxPerPage: perPageCount, cancellationToken: ct);

        do
        {
            await foreach (var page in select.AsPages().WithCancellation(ct)) //note under the hood the ConfigureAwait is already specified, no need to specifiy it again. Honorable mention you can specify a different cancellation source token and combine them if you don't want a single use token for cancellations
            {
                if (page.ContinuationToken is null || page.Values?.Count == 0)
                {
                    yield break;
                }

                accumulator += page.Values.Count;
                yield return page;
            }
        }
        while (total > accumulator);
    }
}
```